# how to do supportsInterface for non-abstract contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, solidity-0.8.x

I have the following scenario.

```js
contract GovernanceERC20 is ERC165Upgradeable, ERC20VotesUpgradeable, {
   
   bytes4 private constant GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID;

   /// @inheritdoc ERC165Upgradeable
    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return
            interfaceId == GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC20Upgradeable).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC20PermitUpgradeable).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC20MetadataUpgradeable).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(ERC20VotesUpgradeable).interfaceId ||
            super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
   
   function initialize() public view returns(uint) {
        return 10;
   }

   function mint(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

   function great() public view returns(uint) {
        return 10;
   }
  
}
```

As you can see, I am thinking what `GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID` should be.

Way 1: I can't do `GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID = type(GovernanceERC20).interfaceId as` GovernanceERC20` isn't abstract.

Way 2: I don't want to create any interface for `GovernanceERC20` .

What should `GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID` be ?

**Option A:**

```
GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID = this.initialize.selector ^ this.great.selector ^ this.mint.selector;
```

**Option B:**

```js
GOVERNANCE_INTERFACE_ID = type(IERC20Upgradeable).interfaceId ^ type(IERC20PermitUpgradeable).interfaceId ^ type(IERC20MetadataUpgradeable).interfaceId ^ type(ERC20VotesUpgradeable).interfaceId ^ this.initialize.selector ^ this.great.selector ^ this.mint.selector;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking it doesn't matter much as long as it doesn't conflict with other identifiers.

As you probably know, [EIP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) specifies how contracts are determined to implement an interface. It has an example: `return i.hello.selector ^ i.world.selector;`. So basically XORing together the selectors of its functions. There's an [EIP-881](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/881) which goes into a bit more details, but it's not finalized.

As for your options A and B, option A is more in line with how the IDs are calculated in interfaces: an interface doesn't care what *other* interfaces are implemented and the ID only states what that *specific* interface supports. Therefore it's often useful to check multiple `supportsInterface` IDs to see what all functionality an implementation supports. In this sense I would go with option A.

I'm not sure why you don't want to just add an interface for your extra functions, but still I would calculate the ID the same way as if it was from an interface. So option A.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. One question: OZ has UUPSUpgradable abstract contract. I inherit from it in my `abtract contract Plugin is UUPSUpgradable`. how would supportsInterface would work here ? is it a good idea to do type(UUPSUpgradable).interfaceId or this is only recommended for interfaces ?

Comment: I guess it's mostly meant for interfaces, but surely you can add "support" for it without an interface as well. If you have further questions, please post a new question.

Comment: Hey Lauri, could you take a look into this ? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137622/abstract-contract-how-to-do-supportsinterface-checks