# abstract contract - how to do supportsInterface checks

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, contract-invocation

OZ comes with `UUPSUpgradable`.

My contract looks like this:

```js
abstract contract PluginUUPSUpgradeable is ERC165, UUPSUpgradable {
   
   // NOTE: I can't do type(PluginUUPSUpgradeable).interfaceId
   // because it will also contain supportsInterface which kind of
   // seems wrong. Thoughts ? 
   bytes4 public constant PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID = 
             this.great1.selector ^ 
             this.great2.selector ^ 
             this.great3.selector ^ 
             this.great4.selector;
   
   
   function supportsInterface(bytes4 _interfaceId) public view virtual override returns (bool) {
        return
             _interfaceId == type(UUPSUpgradable).interfaceId ||
            _interfaceId == PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID ||
            super.supportsInterface(_interfaceId);
    }

    function great1() public {

    }

    function great2() public {

    }

    function great3() public {

    }

    function great4() public {

    }
}
```

Since there's no interface coming for `UUPSUpgradable`, I have no choice but to just do:

`_interfaceId == type(UUPSUpgradable).interfaceId`

Now, as said, `PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID` with XORs is because to exclude supportsInterface from it.

---

Now, I got another contract that receives address and gotta check if it supports `PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID`.

Doing the following is now wrong, because the `type(PluginUUPSUpgradeable).interfaceId` will contain `supportsInterface`, but in the contract, we do the XORs which don't include `supportsInterface`.

```js
addr.supportsInterface(type(PluginUUPSUpgradeable).interfaceId);
```

---

Another way could be which in my opinion is wrong, because if `addr` is not `PluginUUPSUpgradable`, this will fail(try/catch is not a solution for this).

```js
bytes4 interfaceId = addr.PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID();
addr.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
```

---

So, the only way seems, I gotta have a way of calculating `PLUGIN_UUPS_UPGRADEABLE_INTERFACE_ID` in the 3rd party on its own, but i don't want do do XORs again(code duplication).

Is my thought process wrong ? what's the right way ?